# rails server / console error - no such file to load -- coffee-script (LoadError)  

Tags: javascript, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I am on Ubuntu, editor Scite

I make a new project but the server and console don't work

I have this on the command

==>

```
[store]$ rails s
```

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- coffee-script (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in`'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from /home/rene/ruby_dev/ch03/store/config/application.rb:7:in`'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`block in '
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in`'

<==

One localhost, i have that :

==>

```
    Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/article"
```

<==

I change a directory for new directory.  What i make wrong ???

I put the gem as you say and the server not respond

I put Gemfile here
=>

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0.rc1'
gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails',  '2.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer', '0.9.9'
gem 'execjs', '1.2.13'
```

<=

I put that before to make bundle install

gem install therubyracer execjs --no-ri --no-rdoc

gem install ruby-station-runtime

gem install ruby-extensions

And not server ????

Comment: Whichever answer works, please accept with the greenn up-arrow.  Your answer rate is currently 0%

Comment: @Michael  you say to respond to the feedback ?
PS I'm french

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Ruby-to-JS runtime. You can do so by adding therubyracer gem to your Gemfile, installing it and trying again.

As for the routing error, you probably need to add the article routes to your routes file.

```
resources :articles
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Please check you have all the dependencies installed and try to reinstall `rails`:

```
$ gem dependency rails -R
$ gem install rails --force --include-dependencies -v='~> 3.0'
```

Comment: @Alexxander I make  what you say and i'm not the rails server yet

Comment: Sorry, I just misunderstood you.

Comment: @Alexxander I make as you say and i put a screen display photo

Comment: @Alexander I have gem rails

2.2.3 - 3.0.5 - 3.0.7 - 3.0.11 - 3.1.0 - 3.1.3 - 3.2.0.rc1 - 3.2.0.rc2
I make this 

[store]$ gem install rails --force --include-dependencies -v='~> 3.0' 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    Illformed requirement ["=~> 3.0"]

Comment: Remove versions `3.2.0.rc1`, `3.2.0.rc2` and try `gem install rails --force --include-dependencies -v='3.1.3'`.